# How to explain the big difference between memory and native store's sizes on disk in Sesame 2.7.7?

Tags: sesame, triplestore

I have a **2.9GB** n-triples file, and I managed to load it in both a native sesame repository with (spoc, posc and ospc indexes) (let call it `repo_native`) and an in-memory sesame repository (let call it `repo_memory`). I've checked the on-disk size of both repositories in the directory `~/.aduna/openrdf-sesame/repositories` and I was surprised that the directory `repo_native` take **1.8GB** while the directory `repo_memory` only take **125MB**.

I don't really have any clue about how to explain that. Is it that persistence in memory repository somehow also used native storage ?

Does some one have an explanation of such a difference in size?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not sufficient information here to diagnose the problem, but if you're uploading a 2.9GB file to a memory store, and the size of the memory store's storage dir is only 125M, that probably means that your data has not been persisted to disk. You likely have not configured your in-memory repository to sync to disk, or something has gone wrong during upload.

And no, the in-memory store does not use the native store's persistence mechanism, it has its own (far less sophisticated) persistence mechanism.

Comment: So you mean that actually all my data are still in the main memory and that they will be push back on disk when the sesame server will be shutdown ?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean at all. What I mean is that your in-memory store is (probably) configured not to persist to disk, or something has gone wrong during upload. But it's impossible to tell what the exact problem is without more details of your setup.